# Ruby multi-line regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a ruby multi-line string (called efixes) that looks like:

```
ID  STATE LABEL      INSTALL TIME      UPDATED BY ABSTRACT
=== ===== ========== ================= ========== ======================================
1    S    hayo32.02   xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2    S    23434.23    xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

STATE codes:
S = STABLE
M = MOUNTED
U = UNMOUNTED
Q = REBOOT REQUIRED
B = BROKEN
I = INSTALLING
R = REMOVING
T = TESTED
P = PATCHED
N = NOT PATCHED
SP = STABLE + PATCHED
SN = STABLE + NOT PATCHED
QP = BOOT IMAGE MODIFIED + PATCHED
QN = BOOT IMAGE MODIFIED + NOT PATCHED
RQ = REMOVING + REBOOT REQUIRED
```

I *only* want to display the lines that start with a number. I am having trouble, it doesn't seem to be matching. I found this solution here, (that I don't truly understand right now):

```
efixes_array = efixes.split("\n").select{|x| /\A[0-9]/.match(x)}
io.puts efixes_array.collect{|x| x.scan(/\A[0-9]/)}.flatten
```

It is only matching the numbers. I want to display the entire line. The end result, I want to display what is under the "LABELS" column.

Answer (score 0):

This line from your example code

`efixes.split("\n").select{|x| /\A[0-9]/.match(x)}`

returns an array with all lines that start with a number.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. I got it working with the following code: `efixes_array.each do |line| if line =~ /\A[0-9]/  io.puts line end`